# What's the meaning of "force an old head on young shoulders"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

From: http://www.no1starwoman.com/ParentingArticle.htm

> The AQUARIUS Parent: This parent will want their child to be as independent as he or she is, and will support the most modern educational techniques. They may also attempt to ***"force an old head on young shoulders"***, they will be friendly, rational and kind.

What's the meaning of "force an old head on young shoulders"?

Comment: I would interpret this to mean that they will expect youngsters to behave as adults; they will demand maturity, even at an immature age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Head' is being used here as a [metonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) for the mind (with 'shoulders', by analogy, referring to the body). Someone with an 'old head on young shoulders' would be unusually mature or wise for their age (similar to the idiom 'wise beyond their years').

Another related concept (especially since the source is apparently related to astrology) is 'old soul' - some people believe that certain children are unusually mature because they've somehow retained maturity learned from past lives.

So, that's the thing that this type of parent may, according to the source, attempt to 'force' - they may expect and encourage a child to think and act adult at a younger age than children generally do.